# How to force a Joomla Article to use a given template

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

I am working on a Joomla site: http://phillipswebster.com/defective-drugs/yaz has a form and all the rest of its pieces but http://phillipswebster.com/defective-drugs/propecia which I just created doesn't have the form and banner.  I have checked the yaz article and the Propecia article side by side in the admin and they are setup identical.

any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic word here is "modules". You have to activate the same modules (contact module, left menu module, etc.) for the home menu item.